# How to remove attributes from a file in Linux?

Tags: linux

From the command line, how could I for example remove all RW attributes from a file?

Thanks

Comment: You're talking about _permissions_, not attributes.  File attributes are something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
chmod a-rw <filename>
```